# PowerBi with ConnectionString

Tags: powerbi

I can get a database and use this information in PowerBi (I inform the server, the name of the database, etc). However, I want to do the same thing as passing the connectionstring. Instead of connecting to the databaseindicating the databasename, connect using a connection string. Any tips? I didn't want to use an ODBC.

Is it possible for the same PowerBi to be used with more than one database? WebConfig database.

[Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s2qs.png)

[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI06n.png)

[Image 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5rCH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Sever Database connection properties cannot use a connection string. This is due to the Power Query using a different provider behind the scenes to optimise performance. So you are limited to server and database details.

You can connect to more than one database at a time, however you will have to create a new query.